# Optimizing Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, optimization

I have a powerful dedicated server:

**Intel® Xeon® X3440 Quadcore 4x 2.1 GHz
Ram: 16 GB.**

I run on this server just 1 social network website with max 700 users online. Usually server load is ~0.10-0.30 but sometimes it stays above 1 for 20-30-30... minutes. I think this is too high for this machine and it looks that such a high load causes Apache. Any suggestions for Apache optimization?

**Apache settings:**

```
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
StartServers         15
MinSpareServers       10
MaxSpareServers      20
ServerLimit      512
MaxClients          512
MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

**Top:**

```
top - 21:41:05 up 34 days, 10:14,  1 user,  load average: 0.92, 1.27, 1.15
Tasks: 366 total,   1 running, 364 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.4%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.0%id,  0.5%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16468076k total, 14457456k used,  2010620k free,   498432k buffers
Swap:  1999984k total,        0k used,  1999984k free, 12011784k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
    1 root      20   0 10316  748  624 S    0  0.0   2:31.43 init
    2 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:13.22 migration/0
    4 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:01.34 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   6:20.64 watchdog/0
    6 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:21.92 migration/1
    7 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.84 ksoftirqd/1
    8 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:16.12 watchdog/1
    9 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:23.18 migration/2
   10 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:01.20 ksoftirqd/2
   11 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:08.38 watchdog/2
   12 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:18.00 migration/3
   13 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:22.56 ksoftirqd/3
   14 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:06.02 watchdog/3
   15 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:26.80 migration/4
   16 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:07.84 ksoftirqd/4
   17 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:04.66 watchdog/4
   18 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:12.92 migration/5
   19 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:01.38 ksoftirqd/5
   20 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:09.54 watchdog/5
   21 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:11.08 migration/6
   22 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:06.50 ksoftirqd/6
   23 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:05.82 watchdog/6
   24 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:09.52 migration/7
   25 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:16.72 ksoftirqd/7
   26 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:07.90 watchdog/7
   27 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0  17:35.58 events/0
   28 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   7:27.51 events/1
   29 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0  15:10.69 events/2
   30 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   8:15.37 events/3
   31 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0 129:44.39 events/4
   32 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0  24:12.41 events/5
   33 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0 197:43.90 events/6
   34 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0  12:59.56 events/7
   35 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:28.38 khelper
   76 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:06.54 kblockd/0
   77 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.14 kblockd/1
   78 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.22 kblockd/2
   79 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:05.96 kblockd/3
   80 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:02.04 kblockd/4
   81 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.62 kblockd/5
   82 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:01.46 kblockd/6
   83 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:09.78 kblockd/7
   89 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 ksuspend_usbd
   95 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 khubd
   98 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kseriod
  217 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 pdflush
  218 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0  17:56.07 pdflush
  219 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:43.79 kswapd0
  220 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 aio/0
  221 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 aio/1
  222 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 aio/2
  223 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 aio/3
  224 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 aio/4
  225 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 aio/5
  226 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 aio/6
  227 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 aio/7
  475 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 ata/0
  476 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 ata/1
  477 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 ata/2
  478 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 ata/3
  479 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 ata/4
  480 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 ata/5
  481 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 ata/6
  482 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 ata/7
  483 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_aux
 1007 root      20   0 24948 1404  780 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 screen
 1008 root      20   0 18880 2024 1424 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 bash
 1036 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_0
 1037 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_1
 1038 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_2
 1039 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_3
 1040 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_4
 1041 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_5
 1168 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:05.38 md0_raid1
 1176 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   1132:42 md1_raid1
 1229 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0  35:26.18 kjournald
 1310 root      16  -4 16936 1156  496 S    0  0.0   0:00.08 udevd
 1978 root      39  19     0    0    0 S    0  0.0 671:23.34 kipmi0
 2210 root      20   0  183m 2404 1024 S    0  0.0   7:20.61 rsyslogd
 2272 root      20   0 17316 1440 1152 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 mysqld_safe
 2309 mysql     20   0  433m  79m 6612 S    0  0.5   6573:31 mysqld
 2310 root      20   0  3784  604  504 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 logger
 2696 Debian-e  20   0 40656  996  608 S    0  0.0   0:00.98 exim4
 2705 root      20   0 19100  900  548 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 ipmievd
 2719 root      20   0 12368  616  436 S    0  0.0   3:46.73 mdadm
 2765 root      20   0 19836 1044  804 S    0  0.0   2:42.82 cron
 2879 root      20   0  3800  576  484 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 getty
 2880 root      20   0  3800  580  484 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 getty
 2881 root      20   0  3800  580  484 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 getty
 2882 root      20   0  3800  576  484 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 getty
 2883 root      20   0  3800  580  484 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 getty
 2884 root      20   0  3800  580  484 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 getty
 2885 root      20   0  3800  584  488 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 getty
 9318 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3520 S    0  0.1   0:00.08 apache2
 9816 root      20   0 24948 1428  788 S    0  0.0   0:00.02 screen
 9817 root      20   0 18880 2024 1428 S    0  0.0   0:00.02 bash
10416 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3636 S    0  0.1   0:00.28 apache2
10418 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3600 S    0  0.1   0:00.70 apache2
10423 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3576 S    0  0.1   0:00.52 apache2
10427 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3548 S    0  0.1   0:00.12 apache2
10428 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3560 S    0  0.1   0:00.36 apache2
10430 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3564 S    0  0.1   0:00.28 apache2
10435 www-data  20   0  190m  11m 3664 S    0  0.1   0:00.24 apache2
10436 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3648 S    0  0.1   0:00.20 apache2
10446 www-data  20   0  188m  10m 3544 S    0  0.1   0:00.06 apache2
10449 www-data  20   0  188m  10m 3624 S    0  0.1   0:00.64 apache2
10451 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3656 S    0  0.1   0:00.54 apache2
10452 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3592 S    0  0.1   0:00.58 apache2
10459 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3472 S    0  0.1   0:00.16 apache2
10461 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3512 S    0  0.1   0:00.22 apache2
10464 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3480 S    0  0.1   0:00.06 apache2
10469 www-data  20   0  188m  10m 3568 S    0  0.1   0:00.10 apache2
10472 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3556 S    0  0.1   0:00.38 apache2
10473 www-data  20   0  187m 9932 3504 S    0  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10474 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3452 S    0  0.1   0:00.46 apache2
10480 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3604 S    0  0.1   0:00.76 apache2
10481 www-data  20   0  190m  12m 3616 S    0  0.1   0:00.28 apache2
10484 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3580 S    0  0.1   0:00.08 apache2
10489 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3544 S    0  0.1   0:00.16 apache2
10496 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3544 S    0  0.1   0:00.14 apache2
10508 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3528 S    0  0.1   0:00.36 apache2
10532 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3592 S    0  0.1   0:00.50 apache2
10533 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3524 S    0  0.1   0:00.38 apache2
10535 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3484 S    0  0.1   0:00.06 apache2
10537 www-data  20   0  188m  10m 3552 S    0  0.1   0:00.46 apache2
10538 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3564 S    0  0.1   0:00.20 apache2
10540 www-data  20   0  191m  11m 3588 S    0  0.1   0:00.62 apache2
10541 www-data  20   0  187m 9836 3620 S    0  0.1   0:00.14 apache2
10542 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3496 S    0  0.1   0:00.06 apache2
10548 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3644 S    0  0.1   0:00.06 apache2
10550 www-data  20   0  187m 9.8m 3508 S    0  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10554 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3488 S    0  0.1   0:00.18 apache2
10560 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3476 S    0  0.1   0:00.70 apache2
10575 www-data  20   0  190m  11m 3584 S    0  0.1   0:00.34 apache2
10577 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3536 S    0  0.1   0:00.22 apache2
10580 www-data  20   0  187m 9532 3576 S    0  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10581 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3388 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10583 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3624 S    0  0.1   0:00.24 apache2
10588 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3424 S    0  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10591 www-data  20   0  188m  10m 3612 S    0  0.1   0:00.14 apache2
10593 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3508 S    0  0.1   0:00.06 apache2
10594 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3612 S    0  0.1   0:00.24 apache2
10598 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3444 S    0  0.1   0:00.26 apache2
10600 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3568 S    0  0.1   0:00.10 apache2
10604 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3576 S    0  0.1   0:00.08 apache2
10605 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3512 S    0  0.1   0:00.06 apache2
10606 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3604 S    0  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10609 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3516 S    0  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10616 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3508 S    0  0.1   0:00.06 apache2
10618 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3532 S    0  0.1   0:00.16 apache2
10619 www-data  20   0  187m 9240 3404 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10620 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3528 S    0  0.1   0:00.08 apache2
10621 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3588 S    0  0.1   0:00.16 apache2
10622 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3544 S    0  0.1   0:00.06 apache2
10623 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3540 S    0  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10624 www-data  20   0  187m 9916 3448 S    0  0.1   0:00.10 apache2
10625 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3560 S    0  0.1   0:00.12 apache2
10629 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3356 S    0  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10631 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3444 S    0  0.1   0:00.06 apache2
10634 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3476 S    0  0.1   0:00.08 apache2
10636 www-data  20   0  190m  10m 3524 S    0  0.1   0:00.28 apache2
10637 www-data  20   0  186m 8988 3404 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10638 www-data  20   0  187m 9.9m 3552 S    0  0.1   0:00.12 apache2
10639 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3432 S    0  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10640 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3612 S    0  0.1   0:00.08 apache2
10641 www-data  20   0  187m 9268 3272 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10642 www-data  20   0  187m 9364 3436 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10643 www-data  20   0  187m 9844 3392 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10644 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3564 S    0  0.1   0:00.24 apache2
10645 www-data  20   0  188m   9m 3416 S    0  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10646 www-data  20   0  187m 9308 3392 S    0  0.1   0:00.12 apache2
10648 www-data  20   0  186m 9128 3504 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10649 www-data  20   0  187m 8912 3244 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10655 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3416 S    0  0.1   0:00.10 apache2
10658 www-data  20   0  187m 9552 3620 S    0  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10660 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3544 S    0  0.1   0:00.10 apache2
10662 www-data  20   0  187m 9488 3216 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10663 www-data  20   0  188m  10m 3452 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10666 www-data  20   0  187m 9808 3380 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10668 www-data  20   0  187m 9452 3508 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10670 www-data  20   0  187m 9904 3592 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10671 www-data  20   0  187m 9960 3492 S    0  0.1   0:00.06 apache2
10672 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3584 S    0  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10673 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3548 S    0  0.1   0:00.22 apache2
10692 www-data  20   0  188m 9.9m 3508 S    0  0.1   0:00.08 apache2
10693 www-data  20   0  186m 8620 3096 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10695 www-data  20   0  187m 9920 3432 S    0  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10696 www-data  20   0  187m 8944 3248 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10697 www-data  20   0  187m 8716 3132 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10698 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3532 S    0  0.1   0:00.14 apache2
10699 www-data  20   0  187m 9320 3300 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10702 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3528 S    0  0.1   0:00.06 apache2
10705 www-data  20   0  186m 6236 1244 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10706 www-data  20   0  188m  10m 3524 S    0  0.1   0:00.06 apache2
10707 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3396 S    0  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10708 www-data  20   0  188m  10m 3616 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10709 www-data  20   0  187m 9704 3500 S    0  0.1   0:00.28 apache2
10710 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3480 S    0  0.1   0:00.56 apache2
10713 www-data  20   0  187m 9576 3348 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10716 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3412 S    0  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10718 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3444 S    0  0.1   0:00.12 apache2
10719 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3384 S    0  0.1   0:00.08 apache2
10720 www-data  20   0  187m 9240 3368 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10722 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3452 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10723 www-data  20   0  187m 9.8m 3416 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10724 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3520 S    0  0.1   0:00.08 apache2
10725 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3544 S    0  0.1   0:00.14 apache2
10726 www-data  20   0  187m 9884 3424 S    0  0.1   0:00.08 apache2
10727 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3500 S    0  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10728 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3620 S    0  0.1   0:00.06 apache2
10729 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3516 S    0  0.1   0:00.08 apache2
10730 www-data  20   0  187m 9212 3376 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10731 www-data  20   0  186m 7636 2240 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10732 www-data  20   0  187m 9120 3268 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10733 www-data  20   0  186m 6224 1232 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10734 www-data  20   0  187m 9280 3396 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10735 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3540 S    0  0.1   0:00.06 apache2
10736 www-data  20   0  187m 9096 3296 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10737 www-data  20   0  187m 9564 3316 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10738 www-data  20   0  187m 9196 3376 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10739 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3440 S    0  0.1   0:00.12 apache2
10788 www-data  20   0  187m 9288 3404 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10789 www-data  20   0  187m 9224 3368 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10790 www-data  20   0  186m 8604 3092 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10791 www-data  20   0  186m 6224 1236 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10792 www-data  20   0  186m 6212 1224 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10793 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3512 S    0  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
10794 www-data  20   0  186m 8648 3124 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10796 www-data  20   0  186m 8588 3088 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10797 www-data  20   0  186m 8552 3088 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10798 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3384 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10799 www-data  20   0  186m 6232 1236 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10801 www-data  20   0  188m  10m 3456 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10803 www-data  20   0  186m 8544 3080 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10804 www-data  20   0  186m 8552 3056 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10805 www-data  20   0  187m 9044 3240 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10806 www-data  20   0  186m 6204 1220 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10807 www-data  20   0  186m 6204 1220 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10808 www-data  20   0  187m 9756 3344 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10809 www-data  20   0  187m 9264 3364 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10810 www-data  20   0  186m 6224 1232 S    0  0.0   0:00.24 apache2
10811 www-data  20   0  186m 6204 1220 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10812 www-data  20   0  187m 8892 3236 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10813 www-data  20   0  187m 9000 3192 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10814 www-data  20   0  186m 6224 1232 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10815 www-data  20   0  186m 6216 1232 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10816 www-data  20   0  186m 6216 1232 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10817 www-data  20   0  186m 6216 1232 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10818 www-data  20   0  186m 6208 1224 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10819 www-data  20   0  187m 9104 3276 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10820 www-data  20   0  186m 6220 1236 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10821 www-data  20   0  186m 6212 1220 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10822 www-data  20   0  186m 6212 1220 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10823 www-data  20   0  187m 9220 3348 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10824 www-data  20   0  186m 6188 1204 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10825 www-data  20   0  186m 6188 1204 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10826 www-data  20   0  186m 6196 1212 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10827 www-data  20   0  186m 6184 1200 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10828 www-data  20   0  186m 6188 1204 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10829 www-data  20   0  186m 6192 1208 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10830 www-data  20   0  186m 6188 1204 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10831 www-data  20   0  186m 6184 1200 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10832 www-data  20   0  186m 6184 1200 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10833 www-data  20   0  188m 9884 3344 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10834 www-data  20   0  186m 6188 1204 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10835 www-data  20   0  186m 6188 1204 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10836 www-data  20   0  186m 6184 1200 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10837 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3368 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10838 www-data  20   0  186m 6180 1196 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10839 www-data  20   0  186m 8596 3088 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10840 www-data  20   0  187m 9532 3456 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 apache2
10841 www-data  20   0  186m 8580 3072 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10842 www-data  20   0  186m 5704  764 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10843 www-data  20   0  186m 6192 1208 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10844 www-data  20   0  186m 6216 1232 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10845 www-data  20   0  186m 6204 1220 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10846 www-data  20   0  186m 6216 1232 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10847 www-data  20   0  186m 6216 1232 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10848 www-data  20   0  186m 6216 1232 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10849 www-data  20   0  187m 9104 3260 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10851 www-data  20   0  186m 6204 1220 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10852 www-data  20   0  186m 6188 1204 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10853 www-data  20   0  186m 8548 3052 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10854 www-data  20   0  186m 5912  956 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10855 www-data  20   0  186m 8548 3052 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10856 www-data  20   0  186m 8540 3076 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10857 www-data  20   0  187m 9204 3372 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10859 www-data  20   0  186m 6204 1220 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10860 www-data  20   0  186m 8512 3024 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 apache2
10861 www-data  20   0     0    0    0 Z    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2 <defunct>
10862 www-data  20   0  186m 5540  620 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10863 www-data  20   0  186m 5540  620 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10864 www-data  20   0  186m 5540  620 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10865 www-data  20   0  186m 5540  620 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10866 www-data  20   0  186m 5540  620 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10867 www-data  20   0  186m 5540  620 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10868 www-data  20   0  186m 5540  620 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
10889 root      20   0 40660 2404 1968 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 exim4
10891 Debian-e  20   0 40944 1788 1152 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 exim4
10892 root      20   0 40656 2408 1968 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 exim4
10894 Debian-e  20   0 40940 1788 1152 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 exim4
10895 root      20   0 40660 2408 1968 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 exim4
10896 Debian-e  20   0 40944 1788 1152 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 exim4
10897 root      20   0 19088 1368  844 R    0  0.0   0:00.00 top
12414 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3668 S    0  0.1   0:00.20 apache2
12567 root      20   0 24948 1424  784 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 screen
12568 root      20   0 18868 1992 1408 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 bash
13144 root      20   0 24948 1424  784 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 screen
13145 root      20   0 18864 1964 1384 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 bash
14315 www-data  20   0  191m  11m 3580 S    0  0.1   0:00.16 apache2
14318 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3536 S    0  0.1   0:00.40 apache2
16179 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3676 S    0  0.1   0:00.08 apache2
16186 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3648 S    0  0.1   0:00.66 apache2
18041 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3480 S    0  0.1   0:00.10 apache2
18057 root      20   0  186m  10m 5548 S    0  0.1  50:20.83 apache2
18058 www-data  20   0  190m  11m 3616 S    0  0.1   0:00.10 apache2
18059 www-data  20   0  191m  11m 3624 S    0  0.1   0:00.42 apache2
18060 www-data  20   0  190m  10m 3528 S    0  0.1   0:00.62 apache2
18063 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3512 S    0  0.1   0:00.22 apache2
20041 root      20   0 48868 1208  704 S    0  0.0   1:39.02 sshd
27131 www-data  20   0  190m  11m 3704 S    0  0.1   0:00.78 apache2
27134 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3684 S    0  0.1   0:01.00 apache2
27145 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3608 S    0  0.1   0:01.30 apache2
27299 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3688 S    0  0.1   0:01.46 apache2
27388 www-data  20   0  190m  12m 3676 S    0  0.1   0:01.04 apache2
27402 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3596 S    0  0.1   0:00.54 apache2
27410 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3600 S    0  0.1   0:00.26 apache2
27445 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3660 S    0  0.1   0:00.32 apache2
27448 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3684 S    0  0.1   0:00.38 apache2
27480 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3688 S    0  0.1   0:00.80 apache2
27498 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3644 S    0  0.1   0:00.34 apache2
27585 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3680 S    0  0.1   0:01.18 apache2
27593 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3696 S    0  0.1   0:00.68 apache2
27594 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3668 S    0  0.1   0:01.50 apache2
27613 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3620 S    0  0.1   0:00.66 apache2
27614 www-data  20   0  190m  12m 3700 S    0  0.1   0:00.36 apache2
27623 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3664 S    0  0.1   0:01.14 apache2
27631 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3748 S    0  0.1   0:00.30 apache2
27634 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3668 S    0  0.1   0:00.60 apache2
27643 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3712 S    0  0.1   0:00.68 apache2
27654 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3588 S    0  0.1   0:00.24 apache2
27655 www-data  20   0  191m  12m 3684 S    0  0.1   0:00.32 apache2
27661 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3560 S    0  0.1   0:00.56 apache2
27672 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3560 S    0  0.1   0:00.18 apache2
27679 www-data  20   0  190m  11m 3632 S    0  0.1   0:00.32 apache2
27712 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3620 S    0  0.1   0:00.54 apache2
27714 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3620 S    0  0.1   0:00.26 apache2
27729 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3584 S    0  0.1   0:00.16 apache2
27751 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3616 S    0  0.1   0:00.58 apache2
27801 root      20   0 65932 3012 2396 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 sshd
27833 1w3ertw   20   0 66064 1764 1128 S    0  0.0   0:00.06 sshd
27834 1w3ertw   20   0 19312 2164 1392 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 sh
27840 www-data  20   0  190m  11m 3624 S    0  0.1   0:00.20 apache2
27842 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3644 S    0  0.1   0:00.28 apache2
27843 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3604 S    0  0.1   0:00.50 apache2
27844 root      20   0 32452 1208  960 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 su
27886 www-data  20   0  187m 9736 3544 S    0  0.1   0:00.04 apache2
27888 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3636 S    0  0.1   0:00.78 apache2
27892 www-data  20   0  189m  10m 3560 S    0  0.1   0:00.42 apache2
27893 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3648 S    0  0.1   0:00.28 apache2
27904 root      20   0 18828 1936 1392 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 bash
27920 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 4172 S    0  0.1   0:00.42 apache2
27931 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3640 S    0  0.1   0:00.20 apache2
27932 www-data  20   0  189m  11m 3656 S    0  0.1   0:00.18 apache2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load above 1 for a machine with 4 Xeon cores is nothing.

Load average basically indicates a process run queue; 4 cores with HT enabled means you "effectively" have 8 CPUs. I wouldn't even start optimizing anything unless your load hits 8 or above.

We normally start looking into optimizing something for apache servers of similar configs when load hits 16+ really, then we're really worried. Lower than that - it's a waste of time :)